# unexpected type Required: Variable Found: Value

Tags: java, syntax-error

```
import java.util.*;
public class happy_number
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        String num = in.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++){
            double index = num.charAt(i);
            (double)index = Math.pow((double)i,2);
            System.out.println(index);
        }
   }
}
```

For some reason, the second line in the for loop is returning as unexpected type– required: variable found: value. Any insight?

error: [image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgUUb.png)

Comment: I think you are not handling any case when the input is not a magic number.
Try to give some if condition such that if the final number is magic print magic otherwise not magic

Comment: You run into an infinite loop when you enter a "non-magic-number", since your loop condition (`num != 1`) will never be true.

Comment: @maloomeister yes thats correct

Comment: Side note: This line, `num1 = (int)Math.floor(num1);`, isn't necessary as both `num` and `10` are integers and integer division is already occurring.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't continue to ask you for an input. What is happening here is that the execution get's struck in an infinite loop, for certain types of inputs (in this case non-magic numbers).

For Eg.:
Let's take the example `44`, below will be the values for each iteration in the for loop.

|  | num | num1 | num2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Start | 44 | - | - |
| After 1st iteration | 8 | 4 | 4 |
| After 2nd iteration | 8 | 8 | 0 |
| After 3rd iteration | 8 | 8 | 0 |
| … | … | … | … |

We can see that the execution get's struck in the loop.
You have to exit out of the loop when you get such inputs.

One way to exit out of the loop is to add a condition in the for loop.
Another way is to add an if statement inside the for loop, and exit out of the loop based on the condition.

You have to decide what condition you should use in order to exit the loop, based on your problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

Look on to the loop and the value populated inside. There is no breaking condition found and the correct test for a magic number:

A simple code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number to check: ");
        int num = in.nextInt();
        int n = num;

        while (n > 9) {
            int sum = 0;
            while (n != 0) {
                int d = n % 10;
                n /= 10;
                sum += d;
            }
            n = sum;
        }

        if (n == 1)
            System.out.println(num + " is Magic Number");
        else
            System.out.println(num + " is not Magic Number");

    }
```